# How can i put a log inside an infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, infinity

iI would like to turn this

$$ e^z-1 =  \sum^\infty_1 \frac {z^n}{n!}  $$

into this

$$ \text{something} =\sum^\infty_1 \frac {z^n}{\log_e(n!)} $$

Is this at all possible? thank you very much in advance!

Ps- i apologize of title not adequate , i did not know how to word it.

Comment: First, the second series does not make sense since $\log(0!) = \log(1) = 0$ is in the denominator.

Comment: i apologize , i just meant it as a general example , any value would work.

Comment: Are you asking to evaluate the modified sum ? What do you mean by "put a log inside" ???

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly same as your first sum as you said anything would work

$$something =\sum^\infty_1 \frac {z^n}{\log e^{n!}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure what you're asking, but $\displaystyle \sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\ln(n!)}>\sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\ln(n^n)}=\sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n\ln(n)}>\sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$, the last of which does not converge (ratio between consecutive terms > $1$).

Therefore, $\displaystyle \sum_{2}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\ln(n!)}$ does not exist, but *can a series have a log in the denominator?* **sure**.